# Why Interracial couples always give birth to colored one?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

Whether couple is White male and colored female or White Female and colored Male
but they always give birth to colored one.

Why Interracial couples always give birth to colored one?

Comment: I feel you haven't looked into the matter enough.

Comment: This isn't really a biology question. It's a matter of law and politics. In some polities, a racial classification of people was carefully tracked, and children of mixed race parents were *defined by law* to be "colored". See for example South Africa during Apartheid, and some US states during the Jim Crow period. Children of mixed race parents may or may not inherit characteristics would lead to them being characterized as one race or another by casual observation. [See the Wikipedia article on "passing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_(racial_identity)).

Comment: Anecdotally: They don't.